# Varnish Via and X-Varnish headers: are they needed in production?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, varnish

We have just deployed several varnish instances in production and I'm wondering whether is it ok to unset the `Via:` and `X-Varnish:` headers.

As far as I read Via is only an info header, while X-Varnish is for debugging, but I didn't find info about whether they're optional or necessary.

So is it safe to removed them like this?

```
sub vcl_deliver {
  unset resp.http.Via;
  unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a Varnish/Browser/End-user perspective they are both optional and can be removed.